# Android ListView refresh issue

Tags: android, android-listview, refresh

I'm getting a weird problem when refreshing my `ListView`, it works fine until the device is rotated and then when refreshing it again it goes completely blank. This can only be fixed by rotating the device again(as it is also refreshed in `onCreate()`) but then whenever its refreshed again it goes blank. Problem persists until app is restarted.

**EDIT:**

Some code:

```
private ListView contactlist = null;
private static MatrixCursor matrixcursor = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        matrixcursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"_id","name","one","two","three","four"});
    } else {
        contactlist.setAdapter(new listCursorAdapter(this,matrixcursor));
    }
}
```

this works fine but whenever:

```
contactlist.setAdapter(new listCursorAdapter(this,matrixcursor));
```

is called after `onCreate()` and after the device has been rotated the `ListView` goes blank.

Comment: Can you post some code?  It is really difficult to diagnose the problem otherwise.

Comment: Have posted some code. didnt want to put everything as that would be ~1000 lines but think i got all the relevant stuff

Comment: Did you check the layout used for the landscape view? Maybe there is something not right in it.

Comment: The problem also happens if the device is rotated landscape-portrait plus the contactist.setadapter line in onCreate() works fine, its only calling contactlist.setadapter in other functions after oncreate that causes contactlist to go blank.

Comment: Did you try this on a phone or just the emulator, I had a similar problem some time ago and it happened on the emulator, but on none of the 4 test phones I have at work.

Comment: running on htc desire 2.2. never tried it on the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I managed to fix it by making `contactlist` static:

```
 private static ListView contactlist = null;
```

I have no idea why this worked(just did a trial/error for a couple of hours) so if anyone could explain it that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think your MatrixCursor is actually null. When you rotate the phone as you know the activity is destroyed. So the savedinstanceState bundle might not be null but the MatixCursor then does not get reinitialized. Yes it's static but I have a feeling if it for some chance it's not loaded in the same classloader ... well that static is not going to be too reliable.

There is a method which is most awkwardly named:

onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()

Which I think will help you solve this case. So if you return your MatrixCursor instance there, you can in a later call to onCreate() use  getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to read the data back out. It's not guaranteed to be called, so you will still need to handle the case where you have no stored state. Hopefully this helps.

```
private ListView contactlist = null;
private MatrixCursor matrixcursor = null;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactlist);
    matrixcursor = (MatrixCursor)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (matrixcursor == null) {
        matrixcursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"_id","name","one","two","three","four"});
    } else {
        contactlist.setAdapter(new listCursorAdapter(this,matrixcursor));
    }
}

public MatrixCursor onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
return matrixcuror;
}

public MatrixCuror getLastNonConfigurationInstance() {
return (MatrixCursor) super.getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

Comment: thanks but its still not working. I also tried adding matrixcursor = (MatrixCursor)getLastNonConfigurationInstance(); before contactlist.setAdapter(new listCursorAdapter(this,matrixcursor)); whenever it is called after onCreate() but still have the same problem